# Definite Integral of a partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $U(p,q)$ be $C^1(\mathbb{R^2})$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}U$ the partial derivative of $U$ with respect to $q$. I know that $$\int \frac{\partial}{\partial q}U \,dq=U(p,q)+C(p)$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary function of $p$. But  if I have to compute a definite integral such $$\int_{0}^{q} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}U(p,s) \,ds$$ then the answer would be $U(p,q)-U(p,0)$?

My doubt comes from the statement of my teacher that if $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}U=e^{\frac {p-q^2}{2}}$ then $$U(p,q)=e^{\frac{p}{2}}\int_{0}^{q}e^{\frac {-s^2}{2}}ds+H(p)$$ where $H$ is an arbitrary function of p.

I'm just trying to solve the pde $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}U=e^{\frac {p-q^2}{2}}$ analytically.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is? You are correct, $$\int_{0}^{q} u_{s}(p,q) ds = u(p,q) - u(p,0)$$ Your teacher is also correct, which you can check via differentiation using fundamental theorem of calculus$$u(p,q)_{q} = e^{p/2} \left( e^{-q^{2}/2} \cdot \frac{d}{dq} (q) \right) + \frac{d}{dq} H(p) = e^{(p-q^{2})/2}$$

Comment: you're right @Mattos , but if I integrate between $0$ and $q$ both members of $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}U=e^{\frac {p-q^2}{2}}$, then I just find that $U(p,q)-U(p,0)=e^{\frac {p}{2}}\int_{0}^{q}e^{\frac {-s^2}{2}}ds$. Do I have to treat $U(p,0)$ like an arbitrary function of $p$? I just want to find $U(p,q)$ through an analytical method.

Comment: Yes, $u(p,0) = H(p)$. $u(p,0)$ and $H(p)$ are just the constants of integration for functions of more than one variable.

Comment: thank you, sir.